# Mongoimport monitoring successfully entered row/data

Tags: mongodb

How to monitor `mongoimport` hass successfully saved data into our database? Let's say I have 20,000 rows of CSV data. When I press the button to start `mongoimport`, the user will see the progress.

Is there a way to see each row successfully inserted to the DB, visually?

```
mongoimport --db dbname --collection collectionname  --type csv --headerline --file filename --maintainInsertionOrder
```

Comment: By the way, I am creating a windows application using vb.net

Answer (score 0):

If your mongod uses journaling, follow `local.oplog.rs` collection, there are all inserts in the order.

Comment: ,OP want to see the import progress. Yes as per MongoDB documentation sanpshot capture through "oplog". But OP want to know visually the progress of import statement.